# How can I set the Authentication in MongoDB like other SQL databases have?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I want to set the username and password on the mongoDB, so that if someone is trying to connect to the mongoDB via, mongo shell he should enter the credentials first, without that he cant login to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Authentication is supported by MongoDB in form of standard (username and password)  and Kerberos/LDAP authentication - only available in enterprise commercial versions. These are role based authentication and custom roles can be defined for specific needs.

You must read https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/